# how to implement XMLParsing correctly

Tags: swift, xml-parsing, rss

I've created an app where using XMLParsing I can take the top news stories from a website and display them on the app, and then get a short description as well as connect to the website itself. It works with `http://rss.cbc.ca/lineup/topstories.xml` but when I try to use a different website `https://www.ctvnews.ca/rss/ctvnews-ca-top-stories-public-rss-1.822009` it no longer works. I'm not sure what I need to change to get it working for the second link.

```
import UIKit

class RSSTableViewController: UITableViewController, URLSessionTaskDelegate, XMLParserDelegate
{
    private static let displayCardSegueID = "displayCard"
    
    private let urlPath = "https://www.ctvnews.ca/rss/ctvnews-ca-top-stories-public-rss-1.822009"
    private let DESCRIPTION_ELEMENT_NAME = "description"
    private let TITLE_ELEMENT_NAME = "title"
    private let LINK_ELEMENT_NAME = "link"
    
    private var dataStore = NSData()
    private var currentElement = ""
    private var processingElement = false
    
    private var currentTitle = ""
    private var currentLink = ""
    
    private var numElemsToSkip = 2
    
    private func parseXML()
    {
        let parser = XMLParser(data: dataStore as Data)
        parser.delegate = self
        parser.parse()
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.title = "CTV News Feed"
        
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
        
        let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
        let request = URLRequest(url: url as URL)
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler:{ (data, response, error) in
            self.dataStore = data! as NSData

            DispatchQueue.main.async
            {
                UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
            }
            self.parseXML()
        })
        task.resume()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    
    // MARK: - XML Parsing
    
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String])
    {
        if elementName == TITLE_ELEMENT_NAME || elementName == LINK_ELEMENT_NAME || elementName == DESCRIPTION_ELEMENT_NAME
        {
            processingElement = true
        }
    }
    
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String)
    {
        if processingElement
        {
            currentElement += string
        }
    }
    
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?)
    {
        if elementName == TITLE_ELEMENT_NAME
        {
            processingElement = false
            currentTitle = currentElement
            currentElement = ""
        }
        else if elementName == LINK_ELEMENT_NAME
        {
            processingElement = false
            currentLink = currentElement
            currentElement = ""
        }
        else if elementName == DESCRIPTION_ELEMENT_NAME
        {
            if numElemsToSkip > 0
            {
                numElemsToSkip -= 1
                processingElement = false
                currentElement = ""
            }
            else
            {
                print("")
                
                let quoteSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: "'")
                let bracketSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: "<")
                let descriptionScanner = Scanner(string: currentElement)
                
                // Parse out image src
                let SRC = "src='"
                var imageLink: NSString?
                
                descriptionScanner.scanUpTo(SRC, into: nil)
                descriptionScanner.scanString(SRC, into: nil)
                descriptionScanner.scanUpToCharacters(from: quoteSet as CharacterSet, into: &imageLink)
                
                // Parse out description
                let P = "<p>"
                var currentDescription: NSString?
                
                descriptionScanner.scanUpTo(P, into: nil)
                descriptionScanner.scanString(P, into: nil)
                descriptionScanner.scanUpToCharacters(from: bracketSet as CharacterSet, into: &currentDescription)
                
                if (imageLink != nil && currentDescription != nil)
                {
//                    print(imageLink! as String)
//                    print("")
//                    print(currentDescription! as String)
//                    print("")
                    
                    // Build UIImage
                    let imageURL = NSURL(string: imageLink! as String)
                    let imageData = NSData(contentsOf: imageURL! as URL)
                    let image = UIImage(data: imageData! as Data)
                    
                    // Build NewsItemCard and add to SharedDeck
                    let card = NewsItemCard(title: currentTitle, description: currentDescription! as String, link: currentLink, previewImage: image!)
                    SharedDeck.appendCard(card: card)
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async
                    {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
                processingElement = false
                currentElement = ""
            }
        }
    }
    
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: Error)
    {
        print("Parser Error: " + String(describing: parseError))
    }
    
    // MARK: - Table view data source
    
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return SharedDeck.getSize()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CardTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? CardTableViewCell else
        {
            fatalError("This cell is not a CardTableViewCell")
        }

        // Get the appropriate card from the deck
        let currentCard = SharedDeck.getCardAt(index: indexPath.row)

        // Set the cell properties
        cell.previewImageView.image = currentCard.getPreviewImage()
        cell.titleLabel.text = currentCard.getTitle()

        return cell
    }

    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool
    {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return false
    }


    // MARK: - Navigation

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        if segue.identifier == RSSTableViewController.displayCardSegueID
        {
            CardViewController.setCard(card: SharedDeck.getCardAt(index: (tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `reloadData` should be right after the `parseXML` (and dispatch both to the main queue). You want to reload the data when parsing is done. Right now you're reloading the table right after you submit the network request rather than after you receive the response.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should eliminate the `NSData` and `NSURL` references. Just stick with `Data` and `URL`, respectively. Also, don't create `URLSession` instances repeatedly. Create one and use that same instance for all network requests. Also `data!` is very dangerous, as it will crash the app if, for example, the network request was interrupted. Use `guard let data = data else { ... }` pattern.